# Convert .casa-model to .obj

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a file which has a extension of .casa-model. Is there aany way for representing it in .obj ?[model link](https://www.casa-designer.com/public-resources/furnitures/furniture_832.casa-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `.casa-model` looks like it's a proprietary JSON-format and it doesn't seem to be documented. However, it contains exactly the same information (vertices, normals, uv-coordinates and indices) that you'll find in the .obj (or any other) file format.

The way I would go is this:

1. Load and parse the JSON-file
2. iterate over `casa_model.mesh`

   1. create a new `THREE.BufferGeometry`
   2. create attributes `position`, `normal`, `uv` and fill them with data from JSON (`casa_model.mesh[i].vertices`, `casa_model.mesh[i].normals`, `casa_model.mesh[i].uvs`). Something like this:

      ```
      buffergeometry.addAttribute('position', 
          new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(casa_model.mesh[i].vertices), 3));
      ```
   3. create an index-attribute and fill with data from json (`casa_model.mesh[i].triangle_indices`)
3. At this point you should be able to render the object in three.js, if you still want to have the .obj-file, use `THREE.OBJExporter` to get it in .obj format.